# Mutt: sort last mail first

Tags: mutt

I use mutt and this is in my config to sort my mails:

`set index_format = "%4C %Z %{%Y %b %d %R} %-15.15L (%4l) %s"
set sort = threads
set sort_aux = reverse-last-date-received`

But I get a little problem, my mails still not sorted:

[image]

and under the mails from 2016 are still mails from 2018.

Comment: The 2018 mails below the 2016 mails may belong to a thread (consecutive conversation).

Comment: no. Is all seperated mails.

Comment: Is `set sort_re = yes` doing what you are looking for?

Comment: No still the same.